# $_GET not working in drupal module

Tags: php, get, drupal-7

FIXED!!

I just moved few site's from our server back to local server to use it as dev server.
They are done in drupal, and I'm facing a lot problems, still I managed to get em alive.
So the problem is that i have module that will `$_GET['nid']` and use it to load node in this module. Only thing is that `$_GET` just f's at me and returns empty array. Otherwise module seem's to be working just fine, since when I hard code `$nid` in module, it is willing to print it out and work like a charm.

Here's my code:

```
    //get nid (current node) and prev (previous nodes) if present
    if (isset($_GET['nid'])){
    $nid = $_GET['nid'];
    };
    //echo ($nid);
    //if(isset($_GET['prev'])){
    //      $prev = $_GET['prev'];
    //};
    //if there's a nid given, load it, check if there is a node like that.
    if($nid > 0){
            $processNode = node_load($nid);
            $timeInfo['02_processNode_loaded'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

and then it will keep on doing it's thing. And yea when i hard coded `$nid` it worked like a charm.

Url: `http://example/example?nid=2`

Edit:
Also tester `$server['reguest_uri']` witch came out empty.

Edit2:
Also tested

```
$yrityshyva = drupal_get_query_parameters();
print_r ($yrityshyva);
```

and it's empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have modrewrite enabled? if so, you can try

```
http://example/example/nid=2
```

best,
e.

Comment: It only give's out [q] = example/nid=2
Where i need to get it out as [nid] = 2
firebugs php extension will get it but not my server... :c i guess i can take it and explode it, but i also need more info that is in there ex. &previous=node1 etc. And that works with my "return" button. But atleast i will get the node id if i explode the shit out of it

Comment: Can you do a `print_r($_GET)` and paste the output here?

Answer (score 1):

you are missing closing single quote

change

```
$nid = $_GET['nid];
```

to

```
$nid = $_GET['nid'];
```

Comment: also i had isset with ! :o

Comment: just do `print_r($_GET);` to check the value

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was totally my bad since, i didnt have mod_rewrite on....

Thanks for all who have answered